# Python tempfile.TemporaryFile hangs on Windows when no write privilege

Tags: python-3.x, windows, temporary-files

My environment is Python 3.7.2, running on Windows 10.  I'm working on a directory-selection widget, and I'm looking for the cleanest+surest method to test whether the selected directory path allows write privilege.

Previously I'd been opening a named file by the usual `open()` method, writing a few bytes to it, then deleting it -- putting the whole thing in a `try-except` block.  This was OK but it ran the risk of leaving behind an unwanted file.  Recently I came across the documentation for `tempfile.TemporaryFile()`, and this seemed cleaner way to get the same result, with no risk of leaving junk files on the system.

The problem is, `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` hangs on my system when it's given a `dir` parameter that's a read-only folder.  I've googled around and found [this very old bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue1473760), but it was written against Python 2.4 and was fixed long ago.

Here's a test script I put together to illustrate the issue.  (Note that I've omitted the file-delete that my actual app performs, as it's not relevant for the illustration.)

```
import os, tempfile

def normOpen(checkPath):
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(checkPath,'x.txt'),'wb') as tf:
            tf.write(b'ABC')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Write disabled for '+checkPath)
        print(str(e))
    else:
        print('Write enabled  for '+checkPath)

def tfOpen(checkPath):
    try:
        with tempfile.TemporaryFile(dir=checkPath) as tf:
            tf.write(b'ABC')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Write disabled for '+checkPath)
        print(str(e))
    else:
        print('Write enabled  for '+checkPath)

tryPath1 = 'C:\\JDM\\Dev_Python\\TMPV\\canwrite'  #Full control path
tryPath2 = 'C:\\JDM\\Dev_Python\\TMPV\\nowrite'   #Read-only path

print('First method - normal file-open')
normOpen(tryPath1)
normOpen(tryPath2)

print('Second method - TemporaryFile')
tfOpen(tryPath1)
tfOpen(tryPath2)
```

When I run this script, it hangs on the last line and just sits there (Task Manager shows Python consuming about 10-15% CPU).

[image: Windows CMD]

Does anyone know what the problem might be?  Particularly is this a Python bug, or is there something wrong with my usage of `TemporaryFile`?

In case it helps, below is the specific privileges Windows shows for each of these folders:

[image: Permissions]

Comment: This hang is due to an incomplete attempt to resolve an ambiguity. When the code tries to create a file with a randomly generated name in the target directory, it can fail with a `PermissionError`, either due to missing write access or due to a name collision with an existing directory. To check if it's an access problem, the code calls `os.access(dir, os.W_OK)`. However, the Windows version of `os.access` only checks the readonly file attribute, not file security, so tempfile mistakenly thinks your case must be a name collision and continues to generate a new name, up to `os.TMP_MAX` times.

Comment: If your code is Windows only, then you could implement your own temporary file by opening the file via `os.open` with the flag `os.O_TEMPORARY`. It will be deleted automatically when the handle is closed, or when the process exits or crashes (but not if the computer crashes).

Comment: @eryksun, the app will be used by a pretty diverse group of departments in my company -- I expect it will be mainly Windows but I can't be sure it'll be *only* Windows.  But that may not be a problem if (1) the issue you describe in the first comment occurs on Windows only, and (2) I can cover all my bases by putting the 'alternative temp file' you mentioned in a `try` block, while putting the 'normal' `tempfile` in the `except` block.  Is that a viable solution?  If so, go ahead & make it a formal answer.

Comment: Wow.  My Google search missed this but a direct search on the Python bug database turned this up.  It's got quite a history!  First reported in July 2014, a lengthy discussion thread going up through 2017, and still **open** to this day.  https://bugs.python.org/issue22107

Comment: I'm aware of the bug since I participated in the discussion in 2015-2016. To address the issue, we need a real implementation of `os.access` for Windows, but I'm not going to develop that for an SO answer. (Tim Golden's initial attempt is a start, but it needs work.) We could call `CreateFileW` to check for the right to create and list files in the directory. We could also check the last NT status value to disambiguate the Windows error, but that relies on an undocumented function and undocumented behavior. I can try either approach if you're interested.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for the followup and the detailed help.  No need to press further for a workaround, I got the answer I needed (that this is a bug, not just an ID-10-T error on my part).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A deeper dive than I'd initially done, turned up the answer.  This is indeed [a Python bug](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66305), reported some time ago but which remains to be addressed.

The comments from **eryksun** describe the details -- and it's what prompted me to take a closer look at the Python bug database -- so ultimately that's where credit is due.  I'm just filling it in here to get the question answered and closed out.

The bug affects only Windows environments, but unfortunately it has the result of rendering `tempfile.TemporaryFile` unusable on Windows for this common use case.